# Singleton winform not displaying with Application.Run()

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Problem: *Executing the code below with Application.Run() with no parameters displays nothing.*

Background Information: I have a WinForms application that I'm running and I want the default form to be a singleton, and not show up when I first run Application.Run (I want full control of when to show it).

In my Program.cs, using

```
Application.Run(Form1.Instance)
```

works perfectly, but I'm using Application.Run() with no parameters followed by Form1.Instance.Show() so that I can control when to hide and show my Form1.

What am I missing here?

**Program.cs:**

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run();
        Form1.Instance.Show();
    }
}
```

**Form1.cs:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private static Form1 instance;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static Form1 Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new Form1();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think Application.Run() doesn't return until your application exits, so it never gets to the Form1.Instance.Show() call.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. Using Form1.Instance.ShowDialog() works if I have Application.Run() commented out. Calling Form1.Instance.Hide() doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put   Form1.Instance.Show(); before    Application.Run();

```
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Form1.Instance.Show();
        Application.Run();
```

and handle formclosed event of Form1 t oforce application to exit

> ```
>     private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
>     {
>         Application.Exit();
>     }
> ```